# Show that $f(x)=\dfrac{d(x,F)}{d(x,F)+d(x,G) }$ is continuous.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

> In a metric space $M$, let $F=B[a,r]$ and $G=M-B(a,s)$, with $0<r<s$. Show that $f:M\to [0,1]$, define by $$f(x)=\dfrac{d(x,F)}{d(x,F)+d(x,G)}$$ is continuous and $f^{-1}(0)=F$ and $f^{-1}(1)=G$.

The truth is that I can not think how to begin, I know the definition of continuous function, any help pls!

Comment: $d(x,F)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: If $F=B[a,r]$ why $d(x,F)$ is continuous function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $A$ is closed, $d(x,A)$ is a continuous function.

Here, both $F$ and $G$ are closed sets. Also there is no $x$ such that $d(x,F) + d(x,G) = 0$. Hence, $f$ is continuous.

It's clear that when $x \in F$, $d(x,F) = 0$ and hence $f(x) = 0$

When $x \in G$ , $d(x,G) = 0$ and hence $f(x) = 1$

Whenever $ x$ is not in $F$ or $G$, $d(x,F) \not=0 $ and $d(x,G) \not= 0$. Hence, $f(x) \not= 0,1$

Comment: If $A$ is subset closed of $M$, then $f(x)=d(x,A)$. For all $x,y\in A$, we have $\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert=\vert d(x,A)-d(y,A)\vert\leq d(x,y)$, i.e, $f(x)=d(x,A)$ is uniformly continuos. Why is necessary that A let be closed subset?? thanks for your answer! , sorry, I forgot $d(x,A)=\displaystyle\inf_{a\in A}{d(a,x)}$